# Добавление логики в процесс авторизации

Tags: php, laravel

У объекта `User` есть свойство `status`. Я хочу разрешить авторизацию для пользователей, у которых `status === 1`.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{   
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    //добавил свой метод
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
            'status' => 1
        ];
    }

    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Получаю

```
ErrorException
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::credentials() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 76 and defined
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас два класса с одним именем Request, и вы принимаете как аргумент не тот, который требуется.

Comment: Да вроде бы один класс Request, авторизация изначально делалась `php artisan make:auth`, единственное изменение я описал в вопросе

Comment: Я вижу два класса: `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request` и `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

Comment: @Squidward да, действительно. Спасибо, работает!